# using mysql address of wamp

Tags: mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, wamp

I had installed wamp that come up with PHP Apache and MySQL. I don't need PHP and Apache I am making a Java EE app with Tomcat. I want to connect from a Servlet to MySQL Database

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  con =DriverManager.getConnection 
  ("jdbc:mysql://ADDRESS_MYSQL/DATABASE_NAME","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
```

The reason is I am unable to get the  address of MYSQL, I had opened the `sql.ini` file and saw that it is running on `3306` but couldn't get the address.

How can I get the address for connecting with the DB?

Comment: You are running locally? If so the address is "localhost" or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Use the IP address of the computer that it is running on for connecting.  You'll also need to make sure to add a MySQL user that is allowed to connect from a remote host or IP.

Comment: Is it on your local system? Then it should be `localhost`.

Comment: Thankyou all for quick response I tried localhost but that didn't worked

Comment: Check the system tray icon for WAMP, make sure MySQL service is running. During setup you should have been prompted to setup the root password. In that case, if MySQL is running you should be able to connect to localhost:3306 with root to test your MySQL instance. I suspect MySQL service is not running and needs to be started.

Comment: If you only need mysql, I suggest installing only MySQL and not WAMP (Apache, MySQL and PHP)

Comment: @BryanAllo yes I checked that and it is working.I request to please post it as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the system tray icon for WAMP, make sure MySQL service is running. During setup you should have been prompted to setup the root password. In that case, if MySQL is running you should be able to connect to localhost:3306 with root to test your MySQL instance. I suspect MySQL service is not running and needs to be started.

All the best.